# Using stack to write the program of the sequence T(n) = T(n/2) + T(n/2) + n; T(1) = 1

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
int my_sequence(int n)
{
stack<long> mystack;
mystack.push(0);
mystack.push(1);
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++)
{
int a = mystack.top();
mystack.pop();
int b = mystack.top();
mystack.pop();
int c = a / 2 + b / 2 + n;

mystack.push(a);
mystack.push(c);
}
return mystack.top();
}
int main()
{
for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
{
cout << i << '\t' << my_sequence(i) << endl;
}
system("pause");
}
```

I can easily using recursive to solve it but the question ask me to use stack. My code show the wrong output. I'm not sure how can I do it so can anybody help me to fix, please?

Comment: Please see https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ and show your attempt at debugging this yourself.

Comment: And please don't forget to indent your code when you [edit] your question to improve it. Indentation makes it easier to read and understand what's going on. Also please take some time to read [ask], as well as [this question checklist](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2012/11/24/stack-overflow-question-checklist/). What is the problem you have with the code? What is the expected output? What is the actual output?

Comment: You are popping things off the stack but that doesn't work.  T(2) and T(3) both need access to T(1) and T(4) and T(5) both need access to T(2) and T(6) and T(7) both need access to T(3) and for T(100) you need access to T(50) which is 50 items below the top of the stack.  If you pop things off you won't have them later when you need them.

Comment: A possible hint about your problem though: If you do math operations on integer values, the result will also be an integer value. That means `1 / 2` will not be `0.5`, but rather `0`.

Comment: To get to the value 50 items down the stack you will need two stacks - one to store the results and one to temporarily hold half the items while you are retrieving the one so far down.

Answer (score 0):

Each new value requires a value that is nearly halfway down the stack.  For example, T(100) requires knowing T(50) you need to keep values around so you can use them later.

The problem is: how do you get to a value that is nearly halfway down the stack without losing all the values above it?  A stack isn't random access so you can't just grab the item you want.

To retrieve a value down the stack you need to pop all the values above the one you want, read the value and then push all those values back on.  So where do you store all the values you temporarily pop off?  Well, you can use a stack.

If you are calculating T(n) then the top of the stack is T(n-1) and T(n/2) is n/2 items below the top of the stack.  So to get to it we need to remove i-1 - n/2 values from the stack, get the value we want from the top of the stack, and then put all those values back.

Try it here: https://onlinegdb.com/ByhQ-R9DI

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stack>

std::stack<int> results;

int retrieve(int howfardown)
{
    if (howfardown == 0)
        return results.top();

    int value;
    std::stack<int> temp;

    for (int i=0; i<howfardown; i++)
    {
        temp.push(results.top());
        results.pop();
    }

    value = results.top();

    for (int i=0; i<howfardown; i++)
    {
        results.push(temp.top());
        temp.pop();
    }

    return value;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    results.push(1);

    // The top of the stack is now T(1)

    int n;
    if (argc==2)
        n = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (n<1)
        n = 1;

    // n now has a value (n=1 if there was a problem getting the value)

    for(int i=2; i<=n; i++)
    {
        std::cout << "The top of the stack is T(" << i-1 << ") = " << results.top() << "\n";
        std::cout << "The stack is " << i-1 << " items deep\n";
        std::cout << "T(" << i/2 << ") = " << i-1 - i/2 << " item down the stack\n"; 

        int prev_value = retrieve(i-1 - i/2);
        std::cout << "T(" << i << "/2) = T(" << i/2 << ") = " << prev_value << "\n"; 

        int value = prev_value + prev_value + i;
        std::cout << "T(" << i << ") = T(" << i/2 << ") + T(" << i/2 << ") + " << i << " = " << value << "\n"; 

        results.push(value);
        std::cout << "Push T(" << i << ") onto the stack\n\n"; 
    }

    // so print out the top of the stack

    std::cout << "T(" << n << ") = " << results.top() << "\n"; 

    return 0;
}
```